# Inline Assembly Causing Errors about No Prefixes

Tags: c, assembly, clang, inline-assembly, gnu-assembler

Hello,

So, I'm optimizing some functions that I wrote for a simple operating system I'm developing. This function, `putpixel()`, currently looks like this (in case my assembly is unclear or wrong):

```c
uint32_t loc  = (x*pixel_w)+(y*pitch);
vidmem[loc]   = color & 255;
vidmem[loc+1] = (color >> 8) & 255;
vidmem[loc+2] = (color >> 16) & 255;
```

This takes a little bit of explanation. First, `loc` is the pixel index I want to write to in video memory. X and Y coordinates are passed to the function. Then, we multiply X by the pixel width in bytes (in this case, 3) and Y by the number of bytes in each line. More information can be found [here](https://wiki.osdev.org/Drawing_In_Protected_Mode#Plotting_Pixels).

`vidmem` is a global variable, a `uint8_t` pointer to video memory.

That being said, anyone familiar with bitwise operations should be able to figure out how `putpixel()` works fairly easily.

Now, here's my assembly. Note that it has not been tested and may even be slower or just plain not work. This question is about how to make it compile.

I've replaced everything after the definition of `loc` with this:

```c
__asm(
    "push %%rdi;"
    "push %%rbx;"
    "mov %0, %%rdi;"
    "lea %1, %%rbx;" 
    "add %%rbx, %%rdi;"
    "pop %%rbx;"
    "mov %2, %%rax;"
    "stosb;"
    "shr $8, %%rax;"
    "stosb;"
    "shr $8, %%rax;"
    "stosb;"
    "pop %%rdi;" : :
    "r"(loc), "r"(vidmem), "r"(color)
);
```

When I compile this, clang gives me this error for every `push` instruction:
[image: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix]

So when I saw that error, I assumed it had to do with my omission of the GAS suffixes (which should have been implicitly decided on, anyway). But when I added the "l" suffix (all of my variables are `uint32_t`s), I got the same error! I'm not quite sure what's causing it, and any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can qualify with `pushq`, `mov[q|l|w|b]`, etc. Or the operands with `%[q|k|w|b]0`. The compiler doesn't know that you've clobbered `%rax`, or that you've written to `vidmem`, for example. [(more)](http://locklessinc.com/articles/gcc_asm/)

Comment: If all of your variables are 32 bit, you can't move to 64 bit registers directly. You should use 32 bit registers. `mov %0, %%rdi` will compile to something like `mov %eax, %rdi` and that's invalid (although the error message is misleading). Anyway, if you want operands to be in particular registers, use the proper constraints instead of moving stuff around.

Comment: @Jester Thanks! Yeah, I realized my inconsistent use of 32- and 64-bit registers would likely either cause errors or zero stuff out (of which it did both).

Comment: @Brett Huh. Didn't know about the operand size prefix. That's probably what it was talking about. Thanks, I'm updating my asm with it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably make the compiler's output for your C version much more efficient by loading `vidmem` into a local variable before the stores.  As it is, it can't assume that the stores don't alias `vidmem`, so it reloads the pointer before every byte store.  Hrm, that does let gcc 4.9.2 avoid reloading `vidmem`, but it still generates some nasty code.  clang 3.5 does slightly better.

Implementing what I said in my comment on your answer (that `stos` is 3 uops vs. 1 for `mov`):

```
#include <stdint.h>

extern uint8_t *vidmem;
void putpixel_asm_peter(uint32_t color, uint32_t loc)
{
    // uint32_t loc  = (x*pixel_w)+(y*pitch);
    __asm(  "\n"
        "\t movb %b[col], (%[ptr])\n"
        "\t shrl $8, %[col];\n"
        "\t movw %w[col], 1(%[ptr]);\n"
        : [col] "+r" (color),  "=m" (vidmem[loc])
        : [ptr] "r" (vidmem+loc)
        :
        );
}
```

compiles to a very efficient implementation:

```
gcc -O3 -S -o- putpixel.c 2>&1 | less  # (with extra lines removed)

putpixel_asm_peter:
        movl    %esi, %esi
        addq    vidmem(%rip), %rsi
#APP
        movb %dil, (%rsi)
        shrl $8, %edi;
        movw %di, 1(%rsi);
#NO_APP
        ret
```

All of those instructions decode to a single uop on Intel CPUs.  (The stores can micro-fuse, because they use a single-register addressing mode.)  The `movl %esi, %esi` zeroes the upper 32, since the caller might have generated that function arg with a 64bit instruction the left garbage in the high 32 of `%rsi`.  Your version could have saved some instructions by using constraints to ask for the values in the desired registers in the first place, but this will still be faster than `stos`

Also notice how I let the compiler take care of adding `loc` to `vidmem`.  You could have done it more efficiently in yours, with a `lea` to combine an add with a move.  However, if the compiler wants to get clever when this is used in a loop, it could increment the pointer instead of the address.  Finally, this means the same code will work for 32 and 64bit.  `%[ptr]` will be a 64bit reg in 64bit mode, but a 32bit reg in 32bit mode.  Since I don't have to do any math on it, it Just Works.

I used `=m` output constraint to tell the compiler where we're writing in memory.  (I should have cast the pointer to a `struct { char a[3]; }` or something, to tell gcc how much memory it actually writes, as per the tip at the end of the "Clobbers" section in [the gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers))

I also used `color` as an input/output constraint to tell the compiler that we modify it.  If this got inlined, and later code expected to still find the value of `color` in the register, we'd have a problem.  Having this in a function means `color` is already a tmp copy of the caller's value, so the compiler will know it needs to throw away the old color.  Calling this in a loop could be slightly more efficient with two read-only inputs: one for `color`, one for `color >> 8`.

Note that I could have written the constraints as

```
    : [col] "+r" (color), [memref] "=m" (vidmem[loc])
    :
    :
```

But using `%[memref]` and `1 %[memref]` to generate the desired addresses would lead gcc to emit

```
    movl    %esi, %esi
    movq    vidmem(%rip), %rax
# APP
    movb %edi, (%rax,%rsi)
    shrl $8, %edi;
    movw %edi, 1 (%rax,%rsi);
```

The two-reg addressing mode means the store instructions can't micro-fuse (on Sandybridge and later, at least).

### You don't even need inline asm to get decent code, though:

```
void putpixel_cast(uint32_t color, uint32_t loc)
{
    // uint32_t loc  = (x*pixel_w)+(y*pitch);
    typeof(vidmem) vmem = vidmem;
    vmem[loc]   = color & 255;
#if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
    *(uint16_t *)(vmem+loc+1) = color >> 8;
#else
    vmem[loc+1] = (color >> 8) & 255; // gcc sucks at optimizing this for little endian :(
    vmem[loc+2] = (color >> 16) & 255;
#endif
}
```

compiles to (gcc 4.9.2 and clang 3.5 give the same output):

```
    movq    vidmem(%rip), %rax
    movl    %esi, %esi
    movb    %dil, (%rax,%rsi)
    shrl    $8, %edi
    movw    %di, 1(%rax,%rsi)
    ret
```

This is only a tiny bit less efficient than what we get with inline asm, and should be easier for the optimizer to optimize if inlined into loops.

### Overall performance

Calling this in a loop is probably a mistake.  It'll be more efficient to combine multiple pixels in a register (esp. a vector register), and then write all at once.  Or, do 4-byte writes, overlapping the last byte of the previous write, until you get to the end and have to preserve the byte after the last chunk of 3.

See http://agner.org/optimize/ for more stuff about optimizing C and asm.  That and other links can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem!

It was in a lot of places, but the major one was `vidmem`. I assumed it would pass the address, but it was causing an error. After referring to it as a dword, it worked perfectly. I also had to change the other constraints to "m", and I finally got this result (after some optimization):

```c
__asm(
    "movl %0, %%edi;"
    "movl %k1, %%ebx;" 
    "addl %%ebx, %%edi;"
    "movl %2, %%eax;"
    "stosb;"
    "shrl $8, %%eax;"
    "stosw;" : :
    "m"(loc), "r"(vidmem), "m"(color)
    : "edi", "ebx", "eax"
);
```

Thanks to everyone who answered in the comments!

Comment: No, it still has undefined behaviour, as it modifies registers without declaring them as outputs or clobbers.

Comment: Can't you ask the compiler for inputs to be in specific registers?  Then you can drop the extra `movl` instructions.  Also, `stos` is unnecessarily slow.  On Intel CPUs, it decodes to 3 uops.  Using `mov` for both stores would be faster.  The 2nd can use an addressing mode with a displacement of 1 to compensate for not incrementing `%edi` with `stosb`.